# Passing char* through several methods doesn't work at the end

Tags: c++

I'm having problem with getting the value of class member after assigning like that:

```
bool ModeData::setPasswd(char* _pass)
{
    return (this->setString(this->passwd_, _pass) ? true : false);
}

bool ModeData::setOutput(char* _out)
{
    return (this->setString(this->output_, _out) ? true : false);
}
```

where setString is like that:

```
bool ModeData::setString(char* _toStr, char* _fromStr)
{
    // check if already exists and delete
    this->delIfPresent(_toStr);

    // allocate space for the new string
    _toStr = new char[strlen(_fromStr) + 1];

    // copy new string
    if(strcpy(_toStr, _fromStr))
    {
        return true;
    }

    // if something gone wrong return 'false'
    return false;
}
```

and then if I want to print the value of this->passwd_, I get nothing.
I think the pointers are lost somewhere when passing through methods, but I'm not sure.

Comment: An unrelated tip for you: If `(expression)` is true or false, then `((expression) ? true : false)`  is the same.  Just more typing and less readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass your pointers by ref... No, NO! Wait a moment. You should **not** use pointers, you should use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead! That will make your life so much easier.

This said, if you *really* want to use pointers, then the problem is that you are passing them by value. The changes done to those pointers (in particular, the assignment in `_toStr = new char[strlen(_fromStr) + 1];`) won't be visible to the caller once the function returns - and as a side effect, your program is leaking memory.

To fix this, pass your pointers *by reference*:

```
    bool ModeData::setString(char*& _toStr, char*& _fromStr)
//                                ^              ^
```

And don't forget to `delete[]` arrays allocated with `new[]`, or you will have a memory leak. But let me give you that advice once more: use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of doing manual memory management through raw pointers.

Comment: My eyes bleed whenever I see a reference to a pointer. Good advice nonetheless. :)

Comment: Yes, `*&` is really better than `**` way.